# Unity Xcode Build fail- Unityframework Error: Undefined symbol

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

My unity project with firebase integrated got errors while archiving the Xcode project. I have searched for some issues that may be the same as mine, but with no luck. I have tried to install cocoa pods and success to build the Xcode project with no errors. When I archived the Xcode project, it shows so many Undefined symbols like the picture below
[image]

Xcode Version: 14.1.
Firebase SDK Version: 10.0.1.
Unity Version: 2021.3.7f1.

Comment: Did you open the xcworkspace file in Xcode? That's the one you need to use, not the xcodeproject file. You may need to change the dependency resolver settings in Unity to generate the cocoa pods project.

Comment: Yes, I use the Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace to Open the Xcode project. I set the ios resolver setting to default(there is a button called "Reset to Defaults". I am not sure what else I need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the MLKit hasn't supported Firebase 10 yet, so something went wrong. Not sure why my unity didn't show errors. I manually install pod by terminal and got errors. Then I found the same issue as mine here.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10359

The quick answer is to add a version specifier to the Podfile
pod 'FirebaseAuth', '>= 9.6.0'